# PHP wait for sqlsrv_query to finish

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

When I execute a statement from PHP using sqlsrv_query, the order is being sent to the DB but the code continues before the DB even replies. The stored procedure takes about 30 min, yet my code continues as if everything is ok. How can I wait for sqlsrv_query to finish?

Here is part of my code:

```
$SQLserverName = "xxx";
$SQLconnectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxx", "UID"=>"xxx", "PWD"=>"xxx");
$SQLconn = sqlsrv_connect( $SQLserverName, $SQLconnectionInfo);

$SQLquery = $Str;
$SQLqueryResult = sqlsrv_query($SQLconn, $SQLquery);
if ($SQLqueryResult === False) {
    exit("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), True)."</pre>");
    sqlsrv_close($SQLconn);
    exit();
}
sqlsrv_close($SQLconn);
```

Shouldn't the PHP code wait for 30 minutes on line 6 for the query ( that is an EXEC statement by the way) to finish?

Thanks

EDIT: the query has multiple statements in it

Comment: do you see any errors in sqlsrv_errors()?

Comment: no. I edited my question by noting the query has multiple statements in it

Comment: Any errors in SQL Server log file? Thanks.

Comment: you have two options: 1)  you have sql errors 2) your sql query was finished. Double check you SQL query. PHP can't put a process on the background and don't' wait.

Comment: there are no errors anywhere. the SQL queries were tested on SQL server before being inserted in the PHP backend. basically, it is two "exec" procedure separated by a semi-colon.

Comment: it seems SQL server doesn't accept multi-statements in a single query. only MySQL does. can anyone confirm this?